# ADOdb - PHP + MySQL class scope and connection

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

I've just switched over to using ADODB with MySQL and PHP... I'm having troubles with connecting to the database. Before, I could just have one global connection to the database and run queries of of that, but now it seems I need a new connection in each class?

Is that how it's supposed to work or am I doing something wrong?

**Connection made in config file:**

```
include 'admin/db/adodb.inc.php';
$DB = NewADOConnection('mysql');
$DB->Connect($server, $db_user, $db_pwd, $db);
```

**Class used:**

```
class getuser {
    public function __construct($user_id) {
        $userquery = $DB->Execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$user_id."'");
        while($user = $userquery->FetchRow()){
            $this->uid = $user['id'];
            $this->username = $user['username'];
            $this->email = $user['email'];
        }
    }
}
```

The variables used to connect are all set fine. If I were to include the config file itself within then class the it works fine, so it must be to do with the scope of $DB?

Obviously I don't want to have a new database connection for each class / query...

Also, do I need to worry about closing the connection at any point?

Many thanks in advance

Tim

Comment: Just curious. Why oh why would you ever want to use ADODB with PHP by free choice?

Comment: I'm tied to using mysql + php, and this seemed the best/easiest option for easily caching queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not informing PHP that $DB is a global variable. Try the following:

```
class getuser {
    public function __construct($user_id) {
        global $DB;
        $userquery = $DB->Execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$user_id."'");
        while($user = $userquery->FetchRow()){
            $this->uid = $user['id'];
            $this->username = $user['username'];
            $this->email = $user['email'];
        }
    }
}
```